# Taking temporal coherence into account: HMM

Tags: python, random-forest, scikit-learn, hidden-markov-model

I would like to detect sleep stages in 30s intervals, given 4 EEG and 1 EMG signals. Since my EEG and EMG data are just timeseries over 24h, they are temporarily coherent. I am currently using Python / Sklearn.

What I do now is the following: I analyse the EEG and EMG signals and extract relevant features, like power in defined frequency intervals, overall signal power, etc. Afterwards I use my extracted features for classification using a RandomForestClassifier in Sklearn. So far, so good.

I have a paper which proposes the following procedure: It extracts features (like I do), predicts with RandomForest the probabilities for each class (predict_proba instead of predict I assume) for each interval and then to use a HMM to take the temporal structure into account. For example, it is not realistic that the person is in very deep sleep, wakes up for 30s and changes to very deep sleep again. Therefore, the HMM uses the classification result of the RF and predicts the final state, taking the temporal structure into account. The output is the classification, for example to be awake / normal sleep (NREM) / deep sleep (REM).

In this setting, the hidden state would correspond to the classes (awake / NREM sleep / REM sleep), and the observable variable is the probability vector resulting from the RF algorithm.

I would also like to use this procedure, but I don't know how to realize the algorithm. I already read the doc about hmmlearn:
https://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Among others, my problems are:

1. For fitting the Hidden Markov Model: What data do I need to use? My extracted features or the training labels?
2. What is the input for the prediction with the HMM? It must be the observable variable and thus the output probabilities from the RF algorithm, right?
3. If I use the hmmlearn library, what Model do I need to use: GaussianHMM, GMMHMM or MultinomialHMM?

I would be very grateful for any answer, since I'm really stuck in here and do not know any further. Thank you!
Jordin

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of alternatives here

- A: FeatureExtraction -> HMM
- B: FeatureExtraction -> RandomForest -> HMM
- C: FeatureExtraction, RandomForest -> HMM

I think B is what is proposed in the paper. The HMM would take as input the class probabilities of RandomForest classifier.

In C one would concatenate the features (or a subset) and the class probabilities.

In neither model does the HMM see the class labels.

Since your inputs to the HMM are continious and multivariate, I would use a GaussianMixtureModel HMM.